# Converting string into multidimensional char array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

this string is given :

```
S#####
.....#
#.####
#.####
...#.G
##...#
```

and I want to convert it into a 6x6 char array.I know that I can fill the fields like this :

```
    charName[0,0] ='S';
    charName[0,1] ='#'; 
    charName[0,2] ='#';
    charName[0,3] ='#';
    charName[0,4] ='#';
    charName[0,5] ='#';
```

However this cost much time and I think there is a better way to do it. Thank you for any kind of help :)

Comment: Is it a multiline string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it as your string is a multiline one. So it must have **'\n'** at the end of each line except the last one. So you first should split the string into a array of lines. Then from each line take each character and put it into the character array.

*Here it is,*

```
string input = "S#####\n.....#\n#.####\n#.####\n...#.G\n##...#";

char[,] charArray = new char[6, 6];

var lines = input.Split(new [] { '\n' });
int row = 0;
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    int column = 0;
    foreach (char character in line)
    {
       charArray[row, column] = character;
       column++;
    }
    row++;
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Finally the ***charArray*** (multidimensional array) will hold your string characters.

Comment: Thank you sir! =)  I already thought about spliting the string.

Answer (score 2):

Simply split by newlines:

```
var s="...";       // your initial string
var arr=s.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine });

// you can then get your characters like:
var ch=arr[0][2];  // would be # in your example
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what you are asking, but I guess you are asking for the way to initialise array. So this is how:

```
    char[,] charName = new char[6,6] {
        {'S', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#' },
        {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#' },
        {'#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '#' },
        {'#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '#' },
        {'.', '.', '.', '#', '.', 'G' },
        {'#', '#', '.', '.', '.', '#' },
    };
```

Though this will not work if your data is arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one..

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char[,] charArray = new char[6, 6];
            Add(0, ref charArray, 'S','#','#','#','#','#');
            Add(1, ref charArray, '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#'); 
            Add(2, ref charArray, '#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '#');
            Add(3, ref charArray, '#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '#');
            Add(4, ref charArray, '.', '.', '.', '#', '.', 'G');
            Add(5, ref charArray, '#', '#', '.', '.', '.', '#');
        }

        public static void Add(int index, ref char[,] array, params char[] parameters)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
            {
                array[index, i] = parameters[i];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Single-string matrix:
            String input = @"S#####
                            .....#
                            #.####
                            #.####
                            ...#.G
                            ##...#";

            var arr = input.Split(new[] { '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


            //Result "S" will be arr[0][0].ToString()
            ////Result "#" will be arr[0][0].ToString()
```